# aws lambda error loading redshift jdbc driver

Tags: jdbc, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I get below error when trying to load Redshift jdbc jar from Aws Lambda.

> java.io.IOException: Unable to load driver: JAR expected but not
>   found. java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:redshift://insightlyanalytics.c0ubofza4jil.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/analytics;user=xxxh;password=xxx
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)  at
>   com.insightly.GeoPerformanceReports.updateRedshiftTable(GeoPerformanceReports.java:154)

code to load the jar is as below..

```
Class.forName("com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver");
```

Redshift jar is located in the jar file uploaded to Lambda.

pom.xml dependency looks as below.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazon.redshift</groupId>
        <artifactId>redshift-jdbc42-no-awssdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.10.1009</version>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.255</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am unable to figure out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 4):

It was a bug in particular 1.2.10.1009 version, where class couldn't be loaded from jar with space in filename. They claim they fixed it in [latest version](https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/drivers/Amazon+Redshift+JDBC+Release+Notes.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, reverting to old version solved the problem.