# No suitable driver found for jdbc:redshift:

Tags: jdbc, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I am trying to connect to my redshift database using `com.amazon.redshift.jdbc.Driver` I wrote a simple class which connects to the database and executes a select query. I have created a simple gradle project which creates fat jar.

When I run it in my local machine everything works fine. But when I deployed it into AWS Lambda, it gives me below error

```
{
"errorMessage": "No suitable driver found for jdbc:redshift://xyz/xyz",
"errorType": "java.sql.SQLException",
"stackTrace": [
    "java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)",
    "java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)",
    "test.DatabaseConnector.grab(DatabaseConnector.kt:204)",
"test.DatabaseConnector.generateHTMLReport(DatabaseConnector.kt:271)",
"test.DatabaseConnector.sendReport(DatabaseConnector.kt:606)",
"test.HelloWorldLambda.runReport(HelloWorldLambda.kt:15)",
"sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)"
   ]
   }
```

I am not sure why the same jar works in local and not in AWS lambda. Below is the code

```
    Class.forName(driverName)
    val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, 
    Properties().apply {
        setProperty("user", username)
        setProperty("password", password)
    })
    val stmt = connection.createStatement()
    val rs = stmt.executeQuery(query)

    while (rs.next()) {
       println(rs.getString("name"))
    }

    rs.close()
    stmt.close()
    connection.close()
```

Can anybody help in fixing this?

Answer (score 4):

If your using Maven, make sure to use `redshift-jdbc42-no-awssdk`. Also, apparently there was a bug in particular 1.2.10.1009 version, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49288246/aws-lambda-error-loading-redshift-jdbc-driver).

The only working version seems to be "1.2.8.1005" which is the oldest available version on the Maven repository.

Another thing that you need to do is to make sure that your jar file needs to be a so called "fat jar" which would contain all of the dependencies of your application.

You can make a fat jar by using `maven-assembly-plugin` as the packaging life cycle:

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>Handler</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>

            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error in an ECS task, the driver was already bundled in the jar, it was a spring boot app. The container worked alright on dev machine, and yet failed in ECS. @Ali Niaki's answer above proved helpful, I tried changing the version number, but instead of downgrading, I upgraded to newer version.

AWS does not seem to keep the document updated with release versions. So use their repository: http://redshift-maven-repository.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/release from their doc, find the latest version and use it instead. At the time of writing, latest version which is working in ECS is 'redshift-jdbc42-1.2.18.1036'. AWS redshift doc still mentions: '1.2.10.1009', which is causing issues.

Comment: the link provided is dead as of now

Comment: Interestingly, their document (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection-with-maven.html) is still pointing to the same repository link.